# How to make EQ wave length affect

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a shape to imitate a EQ wave like in the video from 4:44 and beyond.
I have made a plane and divided it, and trying to animate the positions of the vertices, but there's no option for it. What method would be used for this type of animation to move the wave length up and down, right left as in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjMCyLsRNig&ab_channel=InTheMix

[image]

Comment: you could use shape keys for that....should the move randomly or how...?

Comment: [Bizualizer](https://github.com/doakey3/Bizualizer) is an add-on that allows you to animate the spectrum from an actual audio file.  Ducky3D has a short [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/fK9Umxy1AAs) on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this little node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

animated:

[image]

Comment: I did a bit more research, and found an add-on called: Animate all, which give you the ability to animate the vertices/points. I found it easier than setting up the nodes. 

https://ibb.co/QNvCgWp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8LbhcXDVWY